# calling a cdef in a cdef class

Tags: python, cython

is their any way to make this work, without sacrificing the cdef in cdef caller? (no use of cpdef either)

```
from array import *
from numpy import *
cdef class Agents:
    cdef public caller(self):
        print "caller"
        A[1].called()

    cdef called(self):
        print "called"


A = [Agents() for i in range(2)]

def main():
    A[0].caller()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Cython A[1] will be a python object. If you want to be able to still use cdef, use automatic cast in your caller :

```
cdef public caller(self):
    cdef Agents agent
    print "caller"
    agent = A[1]
    agent.called()
```

You can check with the -a mode in cython to know if you are using Python or C for each lines code. (cython -a yourfile.pyx -> will generate a yourfile.html that you can browse & check).